# Pausing an animation for 2 second and then resuming it in jQuery automatically, (not in mouse-over or mouse-out)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, animation

I have one scrolling image which is in jQuery, it scrolls and logos  of the clients appears in scrolling box and it **keeps scrolling without a pause**.
I can increase and decrease the speed. But for **pause and then resuming the animation in 2 seconds**, I am not able to which I want.
Here is the **link where I have downloaded the source code**    http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-image-scroller/

```
                **The code in html file**
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

          //remove js-disabled class
            $("#viewer").removeClass("js-disabled");

          //create new container for images
            $("<div>").attr("id", "container").css({ position:"absolute"}).width($(".wrapper").length * 170).height(170).appendTo("div#viewer");

            //add images to container
            $(".wrapper").each(function() {
                $(this).appendTo("div#container");
            });

            //work out duration of anim based on number of images (1 second for each image)
            var duration = $(".wrapper").length * 1000;

            //store speed for later (distance / time)
            var speed = (parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width())) / duration;

            //set direction
            var direction = "rtl";

            //set initial position and class based on direction
            (direction == "rtl") ? $("div#container").css("left", $("div#viewer").width()).addClass("rtl") : $("div#container").css("left", 0 - $("div#container").width()).addClass("ltr") ;

            //animator function
            var animator = function(el, time, dir) {

                //which direction to scroll
                if(dir == "rtl") {

                  //add direction class
                    el.removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

                    //animate the el
                    el.animate({ left:"-" + el.width() + "px" }, time, "linear", function() {

                        //reset container position
                        $(this).css({ left:$("div#imageScroller").width(), right:"" });

                        //restart animation
                        animator($(this), duration, "rtl");

                        //hide controls if visible
                        ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;            

                    });
                } else {

                  //add direction class
                    el.removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

                    //animate the el
                    el.animate({ left:$("div#viewer").width() + "px" }, time, "linear", function() {

                        //reset container position
                        $(this).css({ left:0 - $("div#container").width() });

                        //restart animation
                        animator($(this), duration, "ltr");

                        //hide controls if visible
                        ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;            
                    });
                }
            }

            //start anim
            animator($("div#container"), duration, direction);

            //pause on mouseover
            $("a.wrapper").live("mouseover", function() {

                //stop anim
                $("div#container").stop(true);

                //show controls
                ($("div#controls").length == 0) ? $("<div>").attr("id", "controls").appendTo("div#outerContainer").css({ opacity:0.7 }).slideDown("slow") : null ;
                ($("a#rtl").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({ id:"rtl", href:"#", title:"rtl" }).appendTo("#controls") : null ;
                ($("a#ltr").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({ id:"ltr", href:"#", title:"ltr" }).appendTo("#controls") : null ;

                //variable to hold trigger element
                var title = $(this).attr("title");

                //add p if doesn't exist, update it if it does
                ($("p#title").length == 0) ? $("<p>").attr("id", "title").text(title).appendTo("div#controls") : $("p#title").text(title) ;
            });

            //restart on mouseout
            $("a.wrapper").live("mouseout", function(e) {

                //hide controls if not hovering on them
                (e.relatedTarget == null) ? null : (e.relatedTarget.id != "controls") ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null ;

                //work out total travel distance
                var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                //work out distance left to travel
                var distanceLeft = ($("div#container").hasClass("ltr")) ? totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width())) : totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")))) ;

                //new duration is distance left / speed)
                var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                //restart anim
                animator($("div#container"), newDuration, $("div#container").attr("class"));

            });

            //handler for ltr button
            $("#ltr").live("click", function() {

                //stop anim
                $("div#container").stop(true);

                //swap class names
                $("div#container").removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

                //work out total travel distance
                var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                //work out remaining distance
                var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width()));

                //new duration is distance left / speed)
                var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                //restart anim
                animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "ltr");
            });

            //handler for rtl button
            $("#rtl").live("click", function() {

                //stop anim
                $("div#container").stop(true);

                //swap class names
                $("div#container").removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

                //work out total travel distance
                var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

                //work out remaining distance
                var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left"))));

                //new duration is distance left / speed)
                var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

                //restart anim
                animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "rtl");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already code in the example you posted that will stop and resume the animation (the live `mouseover` and `mouseout` event handlers on `a.wrapper`).

You should be able to take the required code out of those functions, and use it in combination with the jQuery `delay` function, or JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function to pause the animation for a specified amount of time.

Comment: I know you mean automatically. That's why I've said in my answer that you will be able to take some of the code from the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event handlers and use it along with `delay` or `setTimeout` to do it automatically. Read the comments in the code. There is one line that shows you exactly how to stop the animation.

Comment: Thank you very much James, I will be looking into it.